# Friendly_id: slug_candidates not naming slug properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have the following in my model:

```
class Dispenser < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId

  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  def slug_candidates
    [
      :full_name,
      [:full_name, :id]
    ]
  end

end
```

This is generating slugs like:

```
=> 'bob-barker-bob-barker-15'
```

**Really it should be `bob-barker` or `bob-barker-15`, but not both.**

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: Not that it is the source of the issue, but you shouldn't have a comma after the last element in your slug_candidates array `[:full_name, :id], <<<`

Comment: what version of friendly_id are you using? did you try using the github master? I think you should always use symbols, otherwise all the fields will get evaluated when the method is called.

Comment: Ok, fixed symbols and comma and using friendly_id (4.0.10.1) ... still no glory

Comment: so it looks like the functionality you're looking for is only available in version 5 https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#what-changed-in-version-50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality you're describing is in version 5

See: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#what-changed-in-version-50

What you've written is essentially just returning an array of symbols which is running through the parameterize method after it's cast to a string ...

```
2.0.0p247 :002 > ['name',['name',15]].to_s.parameterize # this is what friendly_id does in the background
 => "name-name-15"
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 9):

FriendlyId author here. As mentioned earlier, you need FriendlyId 5 for this, it won't work with 4.0.

Also note that you can not use the id field as a part of the slug, because the slug is generated before the record is created.

If you are willing to have the id field in the slug, then there are easier solutions available other than FriendlyId, such as overriding the `to_param` method as described [here](https://gist.github.com/cdmwebs/1209732).

Answer (score 4):

[:full_name, :id] - you can do this only onUpdate (when :id already set)
When you are creating a new record in your DB table this will not work!

For you purpose you should use some like this

```
def slug_candidates
[
  :name,
  [:name, 2],
  [:name, 3],
  [:name, 4],
  [:name, 5],
  [:name, 6],
  [:name, 7],
]
```

end

Or shortly

```
def slug_candidates
  [:name] + Array.new(6) {|index| [:name, index+2]}
end
```

It's simple way to solve this problem without extra SQL query

Answer (score 3):

On slug conflicts, `FriendlyID` by default uses the `UUID` (e.g. something like `2bc08962-b3dd-4f29-b2e6-244710c86106`) and won't accept `id`. So something like this won't work:

```
def slug_candidates
  [
    :full_name,
    [:full_name, :id]
  ]
end
```

But you can provide a custom number after the `:full_name` instead of `:id`.

I did something like this:

```
def slug_candidates
  [
    :full_name,
    [:full_name, "#{User.where(
        first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name
      ).count + 1}"]
  ]
end
```

So I will get slugs like `john-doe`, `john-doe-2`, `john-doe-3`, etc.